# Why is global.Rx undefined when RxJs is linked to via script tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I am setting up an AngularJS 2 app that is bundled using webpack. The output is currently 2 files: `app.bundle.js` and `vendor.bundle.js`. The `vendor.bundle.js` contains my 3rd party dependencies and is around 1.8 MB currently (unminified). The dependencies in my `package.json` are given below.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
```

1.8 MB seems really big to me and would have a significant impact on the user experience as the app will only load for the user after several MB of data have been downloaded. For this reason I want to externalise my 3rd party dependencies to CDN URLs.

However, AngularJS 2.0.0-RC.1 files are not currently available on any CDN that I looked up (I tried cdnjs and Google). As an interim measure I thought I could just link to the bundled JS files in my `node_modules` directory, like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.28/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.28/system-polyfills.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script> 
<script src="/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js"></script>
```

I'm assuming these are the correct files to link to - particularly the `core.umd.js`. The structure in `node_modules` between 2.0.0-beta.17 and 2.0.0-RC.1 seems radically different, so whatever examples I could find on Google appear to no longer apply.

Also, I couldn't find `angular2-polyfills` in the RC package but without it the browser reported various errors, so I had to link to the beta-17 version. Is there a reason why it doesn't exist in RC?

The problem I'm left with is that `global.Rx` is undefined. I can see that `global` is set to the `window` object but `Rx` is undefined on it. What am I doing wrong?

In general, is it advisable to externalise all 3rd party dependencies to reduce overhead and take advantage of browser-caching of CDN-resources, or is it better to take the hit and just bundle them into your app so that dependency management is a bit cleaner and the window object isn't polluted?

Comment: Usually node dependencies don't run in the browser unless they're specifically designed to be compatible with both of them. Is there an Rx.min.js in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes there is an `Rx.min.js` in the same `node_modules\rxjs\bundles` folder but I assumed this is just the minified version of `Rx.js`...?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't catch that you were using the regular bundles the first time reading through. You could try https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js to see if it works, if you're going to go with the CDN route. I found using CDN scripts for everything ended up being a headache compared to just bundling as the project grew, but I don't think I have enough experience to properly answer the question.